# How can I make Google Maps take only 50% of height within a div? (Ionic 3, Cordova)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins

Ionic native google maps should have height of 100% by default.

I want my google maps to take only the half of its containing div (ion-content).
But as you guys know, if I set its height to 50%, the map will not render.

Is there any way to work around this?

or should I make a container div google maps and set its height to 50%? 
but I found when I put the google map div inside another div, it doesn't work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as such:

html:

```
<div class="mapDiv">
    <div id="map_canvas_test" class="map_canvas_test"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.mapDiv
{
  height: 50%;
}

.map_canvas_test
{
  height:100%;
}
```

Result:

[image]

I am using this to achieve showing a map on the top half of screen along with details at the bottom half.